# Как обратиться к private методу из другого класса?

Tags: c#

У меня есть dll импорты которые нужно пометить в Native классе:

```
internal class NativeMethods
{
  [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

  [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
}
```

Новый класс

```
internal partial class HotKeyManager
{
  private static void UnRegisterHotKeyInternal(IntPtr hwnd, int id)
  {
      NativeMethods.UnregisterHotKey(_hwnd, id);
    // Недоступен из-за уровня защиты
  }
}
```

Пробовал так:

```
NativeMethods Check = new NativeMethods();
```

Пишет что:

> Для не статического поля или свойства требуется ссылка на объект

Comment: `public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);` ?

Comment: @Igor, Это я знаю, но хочу понять, можно ли обратиться если стоит `private` ?

Comment: кхм, кхм, `private` и ставится для того, чтобы нельзя было обратиться. Можно, конечно, - через рефлексию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не должно быть необходимости обратиться извне к приватному методу.

Если метод для того и написан, чтобы к нему обращались извне (как в вашем случае) — сделайте его открытым (`public`).

Comment: .Понял, спасибо

Comment: @Дмитрий: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Либо как я знаю в той же Java, это Setter и Getters посмотри, инкапсуляция почитай или своими же словами "Сокрытие реализации для пользователя".